# No hardcoded path

Tags: java, android, file-system

Since i develop in Java, i got into the habit of not putting hardcoded text in my code.

For paths to files and folders I use the code below. I did it in a way that it was easy to set up and quick to understand, but i want to know if there are any solution more clean to do the same work ? A lib just for this ?

So if you have any suggestions, please let me know !

```
/**
 * Your directory respresented as an enum allow you to retrieve path of any directory easyly and
 * cleanly to avoid too many hardcoded text.
 */
public enum Directory {

    /**
     *
     * The following structure is the complete directory where you work, represented in the form of
     * a tree structure. If you need some ressources which are not in your structure, you need to
     * append to it the neccessary directories.
     *
     * An example of such a directory could be as follows :
     *
     * ROOT ("."),                          ./
     *    ASSETS (ROOT, "assets"),          ├─ assets
     *        IMAGES (ASSETS, "img"),       │   ├─ img
     *        SOUNDS (ASSETS, "snd"),   →   │   └─ snd
     *    SOURCE (ROOT, "src"),             └─ src
     *        CLASS (SOURCE, "cls");            └─ cls
     *
     * Pretty easy with few tabs.
     *
     * ROOT  (Environment.getExternalStorageState()) for android 4.4
     */
    ROOT                        (App.context().get().getExternalFilesDir(null)),
        EXAMPLE                 (ROOT, "ex"),
            ASSETS              (EXAMPLE, "assets"),
                IMAGES          (ASSETS, "img"),
                    ICON        (IMAGES, "ico"),
                    /**
                     * For consistency make sure that `version` have only one child and will never
                     * in the future have more than one unique child named `v1`.
                     */
                    VERSION_1   (IMAGES, "version/v1"),
                SOUNDS          (ASSETS, "snd"),
                STYLE           (ASSETS, "style"),
            SOURCE              (EXAMPLE, "src"),
                CLASS           (SOURCE, "class"),
            BINARY              (EXAMPLE, "bin");


    /**
     * The absolute path of this directory;
     */
    private final String _DIR;

    /**
     * Create a new Directory.
     *
     * @param name The name of your root directory
     */
    Directory (String name) {
        _DIR = name.intern();
    }

    /**
     * Create a new directory.
     *
     * @param parent The parent directory if its not your root directory;
     * @param name The name of the directory
     */
    Directory(Directory parent, String name) {
        _DIR = parent.path() + name;
    }

    /**
     * This method allow you to retrieve the absolute path to the given directory.
     *
     * @return the path to this directory with a '/' character at the end. Replace this delimiter
     * if your file explorer use an diffrerent delimiter.
     */
    public String path() {
        return _DIR + '/';
    }

    /**
     * Return a string representation of the absolute path to this directory
     * @return the absolute path
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return _DIR;
    }
}
```

Ex :

```
System.out.println(Directory.ICON); // print : /storage/ex/assets/img/ico
```

Comment: I really appreciate your code. But, this solution hardcodes as well all paths. How about putting all those paths in a configuration file. Hence, any change of any path will not impact your code base.

Comment: Nice answer I know what you mean, and yes, that's right, all of the hard-coded text in one class instead of all over the code. The code you see is an example, I simplified by putting text in hard, however I actually use `App.context().get().getResources().getString(R.string.my_string)` the things here, is that i need to parse my string for get the parent node or the child. Its in that way i think my code is not perfect and where i need some help. Plus, i don't want the user to be able to modify these path, so config file is not really what i want.. i think ?